# C++ Continuous Player Movement

Tags: c++, windows, key

For my program I am making Pacman! I am able to allow the player to move with the key but how can I make it where the player automatically moves, then when you press another key it changes. In a brief sentence, if I press the right arrow key, the player moves on its own without me holding down the key and If I press the up key, the next available corner, then player will keep moving up. Here is my code for the player's movement:

```
void Controls()
{
    if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_UP) != 0)
    {
        text(Ply_X, Ply_Y, 15, " ");
        if( Map[Ply_Y-1][Ply_X] == '.' ){ Ply_Y--; points++; } else
        if( Map[Ply_Y-1][Ply_X] == ' ' ) Ply_Y--;
        text(Ply_X, Ply_Y, 14, ""); cout << (char)2;
    }
    if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_DOWN) != 0)
    {
        text(Ply_X, Ply_Y, 15, " ");
        if( Map[Ply_Y+1][Ply_X] == '.' ){ Ply_Y++; points++; } else
        if( Map[Ply_Y+1][Ply_X] == ' ' ) Ply_Y++;
        text(Ply_X, Ply_Y, 14, ""); cout << (char)2;
    }
    if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_RIGHT) != 0)
    {
        text(Ply_X, Ply_Y, 15, " ");
        if( Map[Ply_Y][Ply_X+1] == '.' ){ Ply_X++; points++; } else
        if( Map[Ply_Y][Ply_X+1] == ' ' ) Ply_X++;
        text(Ply_X, Ply_Y, 14, ""); cout << (char)2;
    }
    if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_LEFT) != 0)
    {
        text(Ply_X, Ply_Y, 15, " ");
        if( Map[Ply_Y][Ply_X-1] == '.' ){ Ply_X--; points++; } else
        if( Map[Ply_Y][Ply_X-1] == ' ' ) Ply_X--;
        text(Ply_X, Ply_Y, 14, ""); cout << (char)2;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way I see is simply set a player direction when you press a key down.

So you will have player direction to be VK_NONE initially, and when you press any key, you will set the player direction to that key.

And later these ifs will be instead of GetAsyncKeyState(VK_UP)!= 0 to be written as: playerDirection == VK_UP.

Comment: Alright, it works. But now lets say I press the right key, and the next turn is three blocks away and I press the up key. My player will automatically stop. Any suggestions?

Comment: It shouldn't stop. Any key press should set the direction only. So you have to copy your first 4 ifs to set the player direction. 

The rest of your logic is the same as before. 

It is very likely that you copy/pasted wrong for all branches. :)

Comment: void Controls()
{
 if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_UP) != 0)
    {
  PlDir = VK_UP;
    }
 if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_DOWN) != 0)
    {
  PlDir = VK_DOWN;
    }
 if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_RIGHT) != 0)
    {
  PlDir = VK_RIGHT;
    }
 if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_LEFT) != 0)
    {
  PlDir = VK_LEFT;
    }
 if (PlDir == VK_UP)
    { ... }
    if (PlDir == VK_DOWN)
    { ... } 
...
}

Comment: No, what I mean is my code works. Lets say the player is moving left. But If I press the up key before a corner is presented, the player stops. How can I make him keep going until he's at the corner, then turn automatically.

Comment: You will have to keep another variable with "secondary direction" and if you block, you should try to advance to secondary direction. And you should make sure that secondary direction should be on the opposite axis (like OX/OY) from player direction.